# How to Enable/Disable MenuStrip Items and Item's Drop Down Collection Items In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how can I disable/enable a MenuStrip Item and How to disable/enable a menustrip item's DropDownCollection particular item.

A Picture is given of my menustrip and "Account Department" is the DropDownCollection Item Which I want to Disable/Enable according to conditions.

I have a line of code which disable Main MenuStrip Item in this case "Departments" is the Item.

That line of code is:

```
menuStrip1.Items[1] = false;
```

**Currently I have no right to upload a picture so here is a link to it**

[Image Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ixhfclkx678nnc0/Menu.png?dl=0)

Comment: ``menuStrip1.Items[0].Enabled = false;``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said you can set the menu item's Enabled property, but It's better to give a name to the menu item that you are trying to change. then you can easily set it's enabled property as you want, for example name it menuitemAccountDepartment and then:

```
menuitemAccountDepartment.Enabled = false;
```

It's more readable and more manageable.

Comment: here it worked when a used
    `menuStrip1.Items[1].Enabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
menuStrip.Items[0].Visible = false;
```

or

Use this [Msdn site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms171655(v=vs.85).aspx)

You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845269/disabling-a-toolstripmenuitem-vs-disabling-a-menustrip-item)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to disable/enable not Main Menu rather Sub Menu Items

Comment: duplicate of my comment

Comment: @WaqasKhan disabling main will disable it's subitems as well

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad:--> Thanks for reply. I want to disable only single sub item not all.

Comment: Yes I Try but "Departments" Main Menu will be invisible.

Comment: ``menuStrip.Items[0].Items[0].Enabled = false;``

Comment: try this http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/244351/how-do-i-hide-sub-menu-items-of-toolstrip.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you named that item as "Menu1", then you can easy enable or disable it:

```
Menu1.Enabled = false;
```